# Bulk action capabilities for react-admin's MuiGridList layout

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am trying to add bulk action capabilities to `<MuiGridList>` component in react-admin 2.9.7. While rendering table like this:

```
<List>
   <Datagrid>
      <TextField source="id" />
      <TextField source="name" />
      <EditButton />
   </Datagrid>
</List>
```

Checkboxes are shown in the first column, corresponding to this demo https://marmelab.com/react-admin-demo/#/categories. That's awesome.

Then I have grid layout (which I am switching to dynamically from list view if that's important):

```
<List>    
   <MuiGridList
            cellHeight={180}
            cols={getColsForWidth(width)}
            className={classes.gridList}
        >
            {ids.map(id => (
                <GridListTile>
                    <Checkbox/>
                    <EditButton to={linkToRecord(basePath, data[id].id)}/>
                    <ThumbnailField record={data[id]}/>
                    <GridListTileBar
                        className={classes.tileBar}
                        title={data[id].name}
                        key={id}
                    />
                </GridListTile>
            ))}
    </MuiGridList>
</List>
```

This looks like a demo at https://marmelab.com/react-admin-demo/#/products but how can I achieve the same bulk actions capabilities as in `<Datagrid>` component?

Comment: It depends on how you want the tiles to be selectable. Can the user click a tile to select it? Or do you want to add a selection control in the tile?

Comment: Preferably there would be checkbox as I've put it in the grid layout currently (`<Checkbox />` element) - however I need to connect this checkbox to the bulk actions